# How to avoid "the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library" message raised for SysUtils.LoadPackage function

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-2007

I'm using `SysUtils.LoadPackage` function in order to load dynamic packages.
Sometimes, it can happen that some packages are not synchronized and an error like this appears (Picture taken from internet):

[image]

In those cases, I would like to manage the exception avoiding the error dialog.
Unfortunately, I noticed that the message is shown in the `LoadPackage` procedure.
Is there a workaround or another function that doesn't raise error dialogs?

Comment: This presumably happens because you've not got the correct runtime libraries installed. That's the problem that you need to solve.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know but we have hundreds of installed applications and packages aren't delivered to customers by me. So, it can happen, independently from what I do.

Comment: It's a mistake for you to try to deal with this in your program. Supply a decent installation program that installs all dependencies. Make sure you can control what is delivered. If the user screws up their install, they get an error message and have to reinstall. How can you hope to recover from a broken dependency?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You'd be right if our were a small reality. Unfortunately I'm not the only developer, we release dozens packages a day. Installer are used for big upgrades only, in all other cases, someone uploads packages in customers database and each client application autoupdate itself. Furthermore, our application has been developed in order to be able to recover from broken dependencies at successive execution.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've skated by so far, but you've reached the point where you need SCM. You need an automated way to ensure that whenever you distribute an update (no matter the size), you always include all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress this dialog which is raised by the system rather than Delphi.

First of all you need to set the process error mode to suppress the Windows dialog that you have shown in your question. Do that at program startup by calling this function:

```
procedure SetProcessErrorMode;
var
  Mode: DWORD;
begin
  Mode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  SetErrorMode(Mode or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
end;
```

The error mode defaults to showing dialogs for critical errors for reasons of backwards compatibility with ancient versions of Windows. [Microsoft say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621.aspx):

> Best practice is that all applications call the process-wide SetErrorMode function with a parameter of SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup. This is to prevent error mode dialogs from hanging the application.

The code above does exactly that. And suppresses the dialog shown in the question.

Then when you call `LoadPackage` you need to catch `EPackageError` exceptions that are raised and deal with them however you choose. These `EPackageError` exceptions are the Delphi runtime's way of telling you that the call to `LoadPackage` failed.

Reading between the lines, I'd guess that you already handle these exceptions and the error mode setting is all that you need to do.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work in my case. I'm executing SetProcessErrorMode in a  FormCreate but the error dialog still appears. Form is itself inside a dynamic package  (The main package loads other dynamic packages). Could this make SetProcessErrorMode not working properly?

Comment: You can easily create an example to show that this dialog is displayed depending on the error mode. I can't know what your program is doing. Please build a simple project to convince yourself of how the error mode influences the system showing this dialog. Of course, perhaps the error mode is being set too late. The correct place to set it is, as I said, at app startup. Do it in the initialization section of a unit in the host exe that loads very early.

Comment: Reading this again. I wonder if you are trying to set the error mode in the package that fails to load. Clearly that won't help. Set it once and once only, in the host exe, in an initialization section for the first of your units that is initialized.